# Creating an HTML table in C# with a new row ever 4 elements?

Tags: c#

This is very simple, but I'm being rather stupid about it. I have a list of elements and I need to create a new row after the 4th element. So say I have a list "One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six" ... the resulting HTML table needs to look like this:

```
+-------------------------+
| One | Two | Three | Four|
+-------------------------+
| Five| Six |       |     |
+-------------------------+
```

If I were using Javascript it'd be very, very clean, something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; <= (Items.length - 1); i++) {
if ((i%5) === 0) {
   $("#myTable").append('<tr class="table-rows" />');
   $("#myTable .table-rows:last").append(Items[i]);
}
 else {
   $("#myTable .table-rows:last").append(Items[i]);
}
```

Well that code might not exactly work, but I'd use the modulo operator to determine when to create a new row then append the data.

You might say that I shouldn't be using a table for this, and I would agree, but this is not the requirement I'm working under. You might also say that it'd be easier to build the table server side (I'm using ASP.NET MVC, so in a controller), but I have to do this in a view that's inheriting List as its model.

I really want to break up the items into groups of 4 (again this is ugly code, and I'm omitting the ugly WebForms viewengine markup for clarity):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i = i + 4) {
<tr>
 <td>Model[i]</td>
 <td>i + 1 < Model.Count ? Model[i + 1] : ""</td>
 <td>i + 2 < Model.Count ? Model[i + 2] : ""</td>
 <td>i + 3 < Model.Count ? Model[i + 3] : ""</td>
</tr>
}
```

This works for the first set of 4, but then each element gets its own row:

```
+-------------------------+
| One | Two | Three | Four|
+-------------------------+
| Five|     |       |     |
+-------------------------+
| Six |     |       |     |
+-------------------------+
```

I feel as if I'm oh so close, what gives?

Comment: Why can't you make use of the same modulo operator in c# ? You can pretty much convert the same JQuery code to c#

Comment: I need to use a table. With the javascript I'm also using CSS selectors to select the last row. How do I do this in C#? It seems that I have to be very procedural in the view. Also: I cannot use Javascript here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use the Modulo operator in C#, in basically the exact same way you might in Javascript.

Your C# code as it is also will give you index out of bounds errors unless your data source has exactly divisible-by-four elements.

EDIT: Example; assuming a Razor C# view:

```
@for(int i=0; i<Model.Length;i++){
   if(i%4==0){
      <tr>
   }
   <td>@Model[i].OutPut</td>
   if(i%4==3){
      </tr>
   }
}
@if(Model.Length%4!=0){
  </tr>
}
```

EDIT: Added the `if()` construct at the end in re: @48klocs' comment!

Comment: Ah the key was the *ending* modulo operator!

Comment: It's maybe a minor one (since browsers will probably render it fine), but this could lead to a `<tr>` tag that's opened and never closed.  You'd just add an extra `if` statement after the loop to catch that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you might be mixing up the `Count` and `Length` properties.  `Count` is generally used on variable length collections (like `List`), while `Length` is generally used on fixed-length collections (like arrays).  I can't tell how your `Model` is declared, but you likely want only one or the other.